# jQuery Dialog error: "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a div from inside of the dialog be the 'close' button of the dialog box, but after passing an event onto it, I get this error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

I've tried intializing it in a variable (with var $this = $(this);) but nothing seems to be getting rid of that error.

My HTML & PHP:

```
<?php

print(

"<div id='dialogBox' class='dialogBox shadow ui-draggable ui-resizable' style='display: block; top:20px;'>".
    "<div id='boxHeader'>".
        "<div id='boxHeaderText'>"._BEANDF_LOG_SELECT. "</div>".
        "<div id='closeBox'>". _BEANDF_CONTROL_CENTER_CLOSE. "</div>".
            "<div style='clear:both'>". 
            "</div>".
    "</div>".
 );
 ?>
```

The jQuery:

```
function initImpactFactorDialog(){
    $("#opener").click(function() {
        ($("#dialogBox").dialog("isOpen") == false) ? $("#dialogBox").dialog("open") : $("#dialogBox").dialog("close") ;
        });

    $("#dialogBox").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        width: 700,
        height: 300,
        position:[440,118],
        //buttons

    close: 
        $("#closeBox").click(function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');

    })
    });
}
```

The dialog box should close when clicking on my custom button.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`close` doesn't appear to be [an option in jQuery UI Dialog](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).  It looks like you're intending that to be part of the `buttons` option.  Something structurally more like this:

```
buttons: {
    close: someFunction
}
```

At that point the key difference here is the `function`.  You're not passing a function, you're immediately invoking a jQuery selector to attach a click handler.  Inside that click handler, you're referring to *the button being clicked* as the dialog.  As the error tells you, since that button element was never initialized as a dialog, it can't be closed.

You don't need to manually create the click handler.  Just use the handler function in the jQuery UI Dialog options:

```
buttons: {
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
}
```

---

**On the other hand**, if you don't want a *dialog* "close" button but want to use this *custom* button, then don't initialize it in the dialog buttons.  In that case you'd initialize a click handler outside of the jQuery UI dialog initialization, and you'd refer to the dialog (*not* to `this`).  Something like:

```
$("#dialogBox").dialog({
    // your initialization options, without buttons
});

$("#closeBox").click(function() {
    $("#dialogBox").dialog('close');
});
```

---

It seems like you're mixing up the two approaches, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned the `close` callback function incorrectly. Consider the following:

```js
function initImpactFactorDialog() {
  $("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#dialogBox").dialog("open");
  });

  $("#dialogBox").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    width: 700,
    height: 300,
    position: [440, 118],
    modal: true
  });

  $("#closeBox").button().click(function() {
    $("#dialogBox").dialog("close");
  });
}

initImpactFactorDialog();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="opener">Open</button>

<div id='dialogBox' class='dialogBox shadow ui-draggable ui-resizable' style='display: block; top:20px;'>
  <div id='boxHeader'>
    <div id='boxHeaderText'>Log Select</div>
    <div id='closeBox'>Close</div>
    <div style='clear:both'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Personally, I would use the dialog box buttons; yet if you want to have your own button, you will assign the `click` callback outside of the assignment of the `dialog`.

Now consider this code:

```js
function initImpactFactorDialog() {
  $("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#dialogBox").dialog("open");
  });

  $("#dialogBox").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    classes: {
      "ui-dialog": "ui-widget-shadow dialogBox"
    },
    draggable: true,
    modal: true,
    title: "Log Selection",
    buttons: [{
      text: "Close",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
  });
}

initImpactFactorDialog();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="opener">Open</button>

<div id='dialogBox'>
  <select>
    <option>Log 1</option>
    <option>Log 2</option>
    <option>Log 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This uses a little less HTML yet gives you a good UI look and a lot of functionality.

Hope this helps.